# How to read a single line of numbers into different variables?

Tags: c++, xcode, variables, cin

Program looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Code

    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6;


    int num[6] = { num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6 };

    cout << "Enter one line containing at least 6 integers." << endl;

    getline(cin, num);
```

Line of input: 1 2 87 1 2 123 44

And I need to store each number into variables Num1, Num2, Num3, etc.

Comment: You're missing to show, how you're trying to read the input in your question!!

Comment: Seriously, show at least some of your own work.

Answer (score 4):

From your output message, it seems like you're expecting *at least* 6 integers as input. That means you want a container that you can add an arbitrary number of elements to, like `std::vector<int> Nums;`. You can then use `std::copy` to extract `int`s from `cin` and push them into the vector with a `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(Nums));
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/QhaO0l).

There may be a reasonable number of things here that you're not familiar with:

1. `std::copy` is an algorithm that copies from one range to another range. The first two arguments denote the beginning and end of the range to copy from, and the third argument denotes the beginning of the range to copy to.
2. `std::istream_iterator` is an iterator type that extracts from the stream you give it when it is incremented.
3. `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)` constructs an iterator that will extract `int`s from `std::cin`
4. `std::istream_iterator<int>()` constructs a special *end-of-stream* iterator. It represents the end of any arbitrary stream. This means that the `copy` algorithm will stop when it reaches the end of the stream.
5. `std::back_inserter` creates another iterator that calls `push_back` on the container you give it every time it is assigned to. As the `copy` algorithm will assign to this iterator the `int`s extracted from the stream, it will push them all into the vector `Nums`.

If that's too complicated, here's another version that uses less library components:

```
int val;
while (std::cin >> val) {
  Nums.push_back(val);
}
```

Comment: Probably he does not have a fixed number of variables as message says "at least 6 integers".

Comment: Great implementation! Probably a little sophisticated for the author :)