# How to read a string of characters and store into multiple variables?

Tags: c++, string

If I prompt the user to enter 6 numbers in one line, for example:

> 3 4 5 6 7 8

How can I store the first number in the string into variable `Num1`, 2nd number into variable `Num2`, 3rd number into variable `Num3`, etc.? I.e., I need to prompt the user to input a single line containing 6 different numbers, and then split those 6 numbers into 6 different variables.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num;
    cout << "Enter one line containing 6 integers" << endl; 
    getline(cin, num)

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if `string` is the right type to use.

And this method causes all 6 numbers to be stored into `num` instead of splitting the 6 numbers up into separate variables.

Comment: That's what arrays are for... It's not practical to use so many variables.

Comment: You already got answered in your last topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614999/how-to-read-a-single-line-of-numbers-into-different-variables

Comment: You should never say `2` or `3` in your code. Magic numbers mean you're violating the zero-one-many rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
cin>>num1>>num2>>num3>>num4>>num5>>num6;
```

c++ breaks string on space characters.

Use 'cin' in place of 'getline'.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use split strings with strtok.

See this tutorial: http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-strings-zeichenketten-stringfunktionen-zerteilen-strtok.html

For C++ we have already a question that might answer your needs: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are asking like this

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
iss >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5 >> num6;
```

However, I would highly encourage you to look into a container (e.g. `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::list`);